# Unity Input System Failing to Handle IsPressed()

Tags: unity-game-engine

ı wanted to add key binding feature to my game. And to do this I downloaded the new input system in package manager.

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static InputManager Instance { get; private set; }

    public bool DashSecondDash { get; private set; }

    public bool Stop { get; private set; }

    public bool Run { get; private set; }

    public bool Gun { get; private set; }

    public bool Shield { get; private set; }

    public bool UseUltimate { get; private set; }

    public Vector2 SentryMove { get; private set; }

    public bool SentryGun { get; private set; }

    public bool SentryMissile { get; private set; }

    InputAction DashInput;

    InputAction StopInput;

    InputAction RunInput;

    InputAction GunInput;

    InputAction ShieldInput;

    InputAction UseUltimateInput;

    InputAction SentryMoveInput;

    InputAction SentryGunInput;

    InputAction SentryMissileInput;



    PlayerInput PlayerInput;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null) Instance = this;

        PlayerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();

        SetInputs();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateInputs();
    }

    void SetInputs()
    {
        DashInput = PlayerInput.actions["DashSecondDash"];
        StopInput = PlayerInput.actions["Stop"];
        RunInput = PlayerInput.actions["Run"];
        GunInput = PlayerInput.actions["Gun"];
        ShieldInput = PlayerInput.actions["Shield"];
        UseUltimateInput = PlayerInput.actions["UseUltimate"];
        SentryMoveInput = PlayerInput.actions["SentryMove"];
        SentryGunInput = PlayerInput.actions["SentryGun"];
        SentryMissileInput = PlayerInput.actions["SentryMissile"];
    }

    void UpdateInputs()
    {
        DashSecondDash = DashInput.WasPressedThisFrame();
        Stop = StopInput.IsPressed();
        Run = RunInput.WasPressedThisFrame();
        Gun = GunInput.IsPressed();
        Shield = ShieldInput.WasPressedThisFrame();
        UseUltimate = UseUltimateInput.WasPressedThisFrame();
        SentryMove = SentryMoveInput.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        SentryGun = SentryGunInput.IsInProgress();
        SentryMissile = SentryMissileInput.IsPressed();
    }
}
```

This is the code for my ınput manager. When I want to get the inputs I just use InputManager.Instance."InputName"

But for some reason it fails to set the booleans true when IsPressed() method is being called.

It works when I just hold my GunInput button. But whenever I move my cursor it sets it to false no matter what.

I also can't use the Vector2 SentryMove while moving my cursor.

It seems it can't handle holding type inputs well. Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I solved the problem by myself. The issue was actually about the control schemes. I had two of them and one was for mouse and the other was for keyboard.(I thought it was working like this...) Because there are two control schemes at the same time if one is triggered the other is being disabled or something idk.

To solve this I removed one of the control schemes and added both keyboard and mouse into that scheme. And it solved all of my problems.

Comment: I realised I still had code that uses the old input system for getting the mouse position to rotate the character. So I tried to convert that into the new system. But unfortunately it didn't work. And worse yet another bug happened. Now i still can't use my Gun while moving the cursor but, if I stop my cursor and shoot that will change the mouse position to (0,0) without moving the actual cursor. Just the value itself changes.

Answer (score 0):

Every InputAction must be Enable() from code first to start listen data. The new input system works like this: You create a binding, select Button as the action type, then use InputAction or InputActionReference directly in the code. You will have 3 callback options: start performed canceled. You must sign your methods created to intercept input, and already in these methods change your bool variable. Sample code below:

```
public InputActionReference moveForward = null;
private void Awake()
{
    moveForward.action.performed += ForwardPressed;
    moveForward.action.canceled += ForwardReleased;
}
private void ForwardPressed(InputAction.CallbackContext e)
{
    move = true;
}
private void ForwardReleased(InputAction.CallbackContext e)
{
    move = false;
}
```

Comment: You are suggesting me to change how I handle the inputs. I actually don't want to change the code. Instead of this it'd be better if I can find what is causing this issue. And actually most of the inputs are working the way I'm using them.